# Hierarchical Query Joined with another table

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

I would like to join result of hierarchical query to set of other tables. I dont want to hardcode `start with` clause in the hierarchical query and would like the hierarchical query to depend on the join table result to do that.

Below is the sample dataset

```sql
create table person( id number, name varchar2(20));

insert into person(id, name) values (1,'Liam');
insert into person(id, name) values (2,'Noah');
insert into person(id, name) values (3,'Oliver');
insert into person(id, name) values (4,'Elijah');
insert into person(id, name) values (5,'William');
insert into person(id, name) values (6,'James');
insert into person(id, name) values (7,'Benjamin');
insert into person(id, name) values (8,'Lucas');
insert into person(id, name) values (9,'Henry');
insert into person(id, name) values (10,'Alexande');
insert into person(id, name) values (11,'Mason');
insert into person(id, name) values (12,'Michael');
insert into person(id, name) values (13,'Ethan');
insert into person(id, name) values (14,'Daniel');
insert into person(id, name) values (15,'Jacob');
insert into person(id, name) values (16,'Logan');
insert into person(id, name) values (17,'Jackson');
insert into person(id, name) values (18,'Levi');
insert into person(id, name) values (19,'Sebastia');
insert into person(id, name) values (20,'Mateo');


create table friends( person number, friend number);

insert into friends (person, friend) values (1,2);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (2,3);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (3,4);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (4,5);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (2,6);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (2,7);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (3,8);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (8,9);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (4,10);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (5,11);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (5,12);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (5,13);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (6,14);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (6,15);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (7,16);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (7,17);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (7,18);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (17,19);
insert into friends (person, friend) values (18,20);


create table party(organizerid number, partydate date )


insert into party(organizerid, partydate ) values (1, '01-Jan-2022');
insert into party(organizerid, partydate ) values (2, '01-Feb-2022');
insert into party(organizerid, partydate ) values (3, '01-Mar-2022');
insert into party(organizerid, partydate ) values (5, '01-Apr-2022');
insert into party(organizerid, partydate ) values (6, '01-May-2022');
insert into party(organizerid, partydate ) values (7, '01-Jun-2022');
```

I want to get all the friends and their friends for a person with a specific party date. Only caveat is, I cant give party date inside the hierarchical query as my requirement to keep it outside.

for example, I want to get the all the friends for a person with partydate 01-Mar-2022

I want to get the result like below. except, I dont want to hardcode value 3 in `start with` clause and I cant add party table as join inside hierarchal query as I have many other tables to join for my requirement.

```sql
select connect_by_root(f.person) root, sys_connect_by_path(f.person, '/') path, p.id, (p.name || ' is friend of ' || pf.name) friendlink, f.person, f.friend from friends f
join person p on f.person = p.id
join person pf on f.friend = pf.id
start with f.person = 3 /*hardcoded*/
connect by nocycle prior f.friend = f.person;
```

instead I want to achieve something like below, but not sure what to fill `<------->`

```
select hq.* from party pty
join (select connect_by_root(f.person) root, sys_connect_by_path(f.person, '/') path, p.id, (p.name || ' is friend of ' || pf.name) friendlink, f.person, f.friend from friends f
join person p on f.person = p.id
join person pf on f.friend = pf.id
start with f.person = <------->
connect by nocycle prior f.friend = f.person) hq on <---------->
where pty.partydate = '01-Mar-2022';
```

| ROOT | PATH | ID | FRIENDLINK | PERSON | FRIEND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | /3 | 3 | Oliver is friend of Elijah | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | /3/4 | 4 | Elijah is friend of William | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | /3/4/5 | 5 | William is friend of Mason | 5 | 11 |
| 3 | /3/4/5 | 5 | William is friend of Michae | 5 | 12 |
| 3 | /3/4/5 | 5 | William is friend of Ethan | 5 | 13 |
| 3 | /3/4 | 4 | Elijah is friend of Alexande | 4 | 10 |
| 3 | /3 | 3 | Oliver is friend of Lucas | 3 | 8 |
| 3 | /3/8 | 8 | Lucas is friend of Henry | 8 | 9 |

Please guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use lateral join to pass a column to the correlated subquery, which allows to emulate its execution for each input row:

> ```
> select pty.partydate, hq.*
> from party pty
>   left join lateral (
>     select
>       connect_by_root(f.person) as root,
>       sys_connect_by_path(f.person, '/') as path,
>       p.id,
>       (p.name || ' is friend of ' || pf.name) as friendlink,
>       f.person,
>       f.friend
>     from friends f
>       join person p
>         on f.person = p.id
>       join person pf
>         on f.friend = pf.id
>     start with f.person = pty.organizerid
>     connect by nocycle prior f.friend = f.person
>   ) hq
>     on pty.organizerid = hq.root
> -- where pty.partydate = date '2022-03-01'
> order by partydate, root, path
> ```
>
> ```
> PARTYDATE  | ROOT | PATH       | ID | FRIENDLINK                    | PERSON | FRIEND
> :--------- | ---: | :--------- | -: | :---------------------------- | -----: | -----:
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1         |  1 | Liam is friend of Noah        |      1 |      2
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2       |  2 | Noah is friend of James       |      2 |      6
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2       |  2 | Noah is friend of Oliver      |      2 |      3
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2       |  2 | Noah is friend of Benjamin    |      2 |      7
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/3     |  3 | Oliver is friend of Lucas     |      3 |      8
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/3     |  3 | Oliver is friend of Elijah    |      3 |      4
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/3/4   |  4 | Elijah is friend of William   |      4 |      5
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/3/4   |  4 | Elijah is friend of Alexande  |      4 |     10
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/3/4/5 |  5 | William is friend of Michael  |      5 |     12
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/3/4/5 |  5 | William is friend of Mason    |      5 |     11
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/3/4/5 |  5 | William is friend of Ethan    |      5 |     13
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/3/8   |  8 | Lucas is friend of Henry      |      8 |      9
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/6     |  6 | James is friend of Daniel     |      6 |     14
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/6     |  6 | James is friend of Jacob      |      6 |     15
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/7     |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Logan   |      7 |     16
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/7     |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Levi    |      7 |     18
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/7     |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Jackson |      7 |     17
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/7/17  | 17 | Jackson is friend of Sebastia |     17 |     19
> 2022-01-01 |    1 | /1/2/7/18  | 18 | Levi is friend of Mateo       |     18 |     20
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2         |  2 | Noah is friend of Oliver      |      2 |      3
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2         |  2 | Noah is friend of James       |      2 |      6
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2         |  2 | Noah is friend of Benjamin    |      2 |      7
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/3       |  3 | Oliver is friend of Elijah    |      3 |      4
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/3       |  3 | Oliver is friend of Lucas     |      3 |      8
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/3/4     |  4 | Elijah is friend of Alexande  |      4 |     10
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/3/4     |  4 | Elijah is friend of William   |      4 |      5
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/3/4/5   |  5 | William is friend of Ethan    |      5 |     13
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/3/4/5   |  5 | William is friend of Michael  |      5 |     12
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/3/4/5   |  5 | William is friend of Mason    |      5 |     11
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/3/8     |  8 | Lucas is friend of Henry      |      8 |      9
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/6       |  6 | James is friend of Jacob      |      6 |     15
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/6       |  6 | James is friend of Daniel     |      6 |     14
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/7       |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Jackson |      7 |     17
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/7       |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Logan   |      7 |     16
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/7       |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Levi    |      7 |     18
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/7/17    | 17 | Jackson is friend of Sebastia |     17 |     19
> 2022-02-01 |    2 | /2/7/18    | 18 | Levi is friend of Mateo       |     18 |     20
> 2022-03-01 |    3 | /3         |  3 | Oliver is friend of Elijah    |      3 |      4
> 2022-03-01 |    3 | /3         |  3 | Oliver is friend of Lucas     |      3 |      8
> 2022-03-01 |    3 | /3/4       |  4 | Elijah is friend of Alexande  |      4 |     10
> 2022-03-01 |    3 | /3/4       |  4 | Elijah is friend of William   |      4 |      5
> 2022-03-01 |    3 | /3/4/5     |  5 | William is friend of Ethan    |      5 |     13
> 2022-03-01 |    3 | /3/4/5     |  5 | William is friend of Michael  |      5 |     12
> 2022-03-01 |    3 | /3/4/5     |  5 | William is friend of Mason    |      5 |     11
> 2022-03-01 |    3 | /3/8       |  8 | Lucas is friend of Henry      |      8 |      9
> 2022-04-01 |    5 | /5         |  5 | William is friend of Mason    |      5 |     11
> 2022-04-01 |    5 | /5         |  5 | William is friend of Michael  |      5 |     12
> 2022-04-01 |    5 | /5         |  5 | William is friend of Ethan    |      5 |     13
> 2022-05-01 |    6 | /6         |  6 | James is friend of Daniel     |      6 |     14
> 2022-05-01 |    6 | /6         |  6 | James is friend of Jacob      |      6 |     15
> 2022-06-01 |    7 | /7         |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Jackson |      7 |     17
> 2022-06-01 |    7 | /7         |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Logan   |      7 |     16
> 2022-06-01 |    7 | /7         |  7 | Benjamin is friend of Levi    |      7 |     18
> 2022-06-01 |    7 | /7/17      | 17 | Jackson is friend of Sebastia |     17 |     19
> 2022-06-01 |    7 | /7/18      | 18 | Levi is friend of Mateo       |     18 |     20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=35ce50cdaf22f7b5c8cfb7a26ec7be27)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solved my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the all the friends for a person with `partydate` `01-Mar-2022`

You can use your query and replace the hardcoded `START WITH` with an `EXISTS` condition:

```sql
select connect_by_root(f.person) AS root,
       sys_connect_by_path(f.person, '/') AS path,
       p.id,
       p.name || ' is friend of ' || pf.name AS friendlink,
       f.person,
       f.friend
from   friends f
       join person p on f.person = p.id
       join person pf on f.friend = pf.id
start with
       EXISTS( 
         SELECT 1
         FROM   party p
         WHERE  partydate = DATE '2022-03-01'
         AND    f.person = p.organizerid
       )
connect by nocycle prior f.friend = f.person;
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | ROOT | PATH | ID | FRIENDLINK | PERSON | FRIEND |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | /3 | 3 | Oliver is friend of Elijah | 3 | 4 |
> | 3 | /3/4 | 4 | Elijah is friend of William | 4 | 5 |
> | 3 | /3/4/5 | 5 | William is friend of Mason | 5 | 11 |
> | 3 | /3/4/5 | 5 | William is friend of Michael | 5 | 12 |
> | 3 | /3/4/5 | 5 | William is friend of Ethan | 5 | 13 |
> | 3 | /3/4 | 4 | Elijah is friend of Alexande | 4 | 10 |
> | 3 | /3 | 3 | Oliver is friend of Lucas | 3 | 8 |
> | 3 | /3/8 | 8 | Lucas is friend of Henry | 8 | 9 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=28925bde3ad14f290b939a375e466aed)*